# ASP .net get hidden value from code behind in page_load function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, hidden-field

I have a hidden field that I set in my javascript code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    function start() {            
        document.getElementById('Hidden1').value = "somme value";
     }
   </script>

 <body>

 <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
      <input type="text" id="Hidden1" name="Hidden1" runat="server"/>
  <div>    
 </form>
```

In my code behind I want to get the input value in my page_load function:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("start") && !IsPostBack)
        {

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "start", "start();", true);

        }
        string message =Hidden1.Value;
    }
```

The message is empty, how can'I get the hidden value in my page_load?

Thanks.

Comment: are you posting/submitting or doing a get?

Comment: when are you executing the start() js method?  nevermind, i see you have it registered in a startup

Comment: so back to my original comment, where is the code that submits the page?

Comment: What code? the javascript is in my aspx page and I want to get the hidden field value in my code behind when my page is loaded

Comment: read my answer, your aspx server code can only read form elements when you issue a submit.  You must POST your data to the server.  I will append my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not submitting the page back to the server, you won't be able to "get" page variables unless you are doing a POST.

change this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
   <input type="text" id="Hidden1" name="Hidden1" runat="server"/>
 <div>    
</form>
```

to this:  (EDIT: changed the `type="hidden"` too)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
   <input type="hidden" id="Hidden1" name="Hidden1" runat="server"/>
 <div>    
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Then click the submit button

Comment: isn't there another solution? I have to get my hidden field in the page load to implement a specific behavior

Comment: outside of posting your data via AJAX call, no.  I'm not sure you have properly explained what you are trying to do.  If you want to set a html element and don't want to submit that data to the server somehow then you have lost me.

Comment: Who told you that there is a submit button on the page? sorry you are making assumptions.

Comment: there needs to be a submit of you are going to read a ASP server control.  That IS the reason there is not a value on the server side.   Your down vote doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes postback is not related to button only.. thats why you can't answer directly without investigating. It does make sense.

Comment: yes, but the poster doesn't show ANY postback code....  in order to read the hidden value there must be a POSTBACK.  The poster even comments on this thread asking for any other way other than POSTING, other answers on this thread also mention this.

Comment: Thanks! @IrfanTahirKheli, your apology is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what others have written (by the looks of it) this works IF you press the submit button so that you get a postback:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value = "some value";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is something along the lines of JQuery post.

Web applications are stateless.

As with some of the earlier posts, it is not sufficient on the server side to get the value of a control on the client without some postback event.  The server has to know what is going on.   In your client-side code, you get the value of the control in your script block, but there is no post to the server to let it know what transpired in the client code.  You need to understand that either you post the form (or at least the data) back to the server or ,if you want this to happen without a full postback, you need to learn [JQuery or Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp).

If you need this to happen without some user event, then do the post in the document.ready function.  However, that is redundant because your server posted the data in the first place, so without user interaction (in document.ready) there isn't anything the server won't already know, especially in a hidden value.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" runat="server"/>
  <div>    
 </form>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if ( !Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           Hidden1.Value = "Some Val";
        }
        else
        {
           string message =Hidden1.Value;
           // remaining code
        }
 }
```

Comment: where is the postback?

Comment: @TMcKeown : Why you voted down? is it necessary to show a button and ask the OP to click it and it will postback. you......

Comment: Because the question is how to get the value of the hidden element on the server side.  The poster isn't providing a way of posting back, your answer doesn't work without a post back.  I like your solution related to seeding the default, I only down vote because it isn't answering why there is no value on the server side.