# retrieve value from javascript function in codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-behind

How can I retrieve value from javascript function in codebehind, on page load ..
javascript function like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function isIFrame() {
            var isInIFrame = (top.location != self.location);
            if (isInIFrame) {
                return "inside";
            }
            else {
                return "outside";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and code behind like :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string resutOfExecuteJavaScript = "";
        // resutOfExecuteJavaScript = isIFrame(); // from javascript

        if (resutOfExecuteJavaScript == "inside")
        {
            // do something
        }
        else
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot directly call a client side javascript method from server side code . For that first you need to assign the function result to value of some hidden variable and then access  it in server side

Suppose you have an hidden field like this

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnVal"/>
```

then you can set the value as below

```
document.getElementById("hdnVal").value=isIFrame();
```

then at serve side

```
 string resutOfJavaScriptExecution = hdnVal.Value;
```

Comment: this is not useful, because Page_Load run before javascript function

Comment: Page_load happens in server side , Javascript executes at client side .  So whenever the value is postback to server you will have this value in the variable . Give  a full picture of the issue in the post

Comment: Check this for your referance http://www.dotnetodyssey.com/2014/12/18/set-value-asphiddenfield-using-jquery-get-value-asp-net-code-behind/

Comment: as you said "whenever the value is postback to server you will have this value in the variable" but I need it at Page_Load

Comment: Check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758137/asp-net-get-hidden-value-from-code-behind-in-page-load-function

Comment: so, you say I can't do this until do postback, right ?

Comment: @Mo7ammed - I think the problem is you don't understand how ASP.NET works. server-side code runs on the server... client-side code runs on the client... they can interact only when the server provides information to the client through the rendering of the javascript, and the client-side code can send information back to the server either through post-back or AJAX, etc.  The server-side code **cannot** run a function that is written in a language that is used by the client-side

Comment: @Midhun - just a small thing, your answer is a good one, but the OP never mentioned jQuery, so you might want to provide a bit of vanilla code as well with an explanation

Answer (score 1):

using _doPostBack, you can solve this one

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
             function isIFrame() {
            var isInIFrame =(top.location != self.location);
            var result;
            if (isInIFrame) { 
                result="inside";
             }
           else
             {
             result ="outside";
             }
           __doPostBack('callPostBack', result);
        </script>
    </head>
```

In code behind section

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "arg");
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string eventTarget = this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
        string eventArgument = this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

        if (eventTarget != String.Empty && eventTarget == "callPostBack")
        {
            if (eventArgument == "inside"){   
               //do something
               }
           else if(eventArgument == "outside")
            {
           //do something
           }
       }
    else
    {
       // set the button click
        btnclick.Attributes.Add("onClick", "isIFrame();");
    }
}
```

Below link will help you out to get more idea.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=203

Comment: Please don't provide links as answers.  Links can go dead, and if this is the answered accepted by the OP then people won't know what the solution is.  Please provide details within your answer, quoting the original page

Answer (score 0):

in javascript file or your script add :

```
function SetHiddenVariable()
     {
        document.getElementById(inpHide).value= "value";
     }
```

in .aspx add this tag:

```
    <input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

in aspx.cs (c# file) add :

```
 anyVariable = inpHide.Value;
```