# How to get value in code behind from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Hello All I am newbie in ASP.NET and trying to get textbox value in code behind but i am unable to do that 
here is the process i am doing 
There is gridview in my project and on rowclick i am calling this script

```
    function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
        var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
        var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
        var customerId = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
        var suggested_plan = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
        var plan_id = row.cells[5].innerHTML;
        var propsed = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
        var previouscost = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('<%=txt_lead_id.ClientID %>').value = customerId;
        document.getElementById('<%=txt_suggested.ClientID %>').value = suggested_plan;
        document.getElementById('<%=txt_suggested.ClientID %>').title = plan_id;
        document.getElementById('<%=txt_previous.ClientID %>').value = previouscost;
        document.getElementById('<%=txt_units.ClientID %>').value = propsed;

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and i am getting values in textboxes like txt_lead_id and txt_suggested as well but when in code behind i am getting
  string lead_id = txt_lead_id.Text; Then lead_id is giving me null values i have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: The code behind is compiled C# server-side code. JavaScript is client-side code that is generated by the server-side code. JavaScript can't directly execute in the code-behind.

Comment: @Scott Marcus So how can i achieve this?

Comment: @ScottMarcus The script is declared in .aspx and i have to get these values in .aspx.cs file

Comment: @AlokDwivedi you have to post your form to server side using ajax or using .NET web form post. you can check the value in page_load method of the aspx.cs page where you are posting when page.isPostBack is true

Comment: @ScottMarcus i am using .NET Web Form to submit the data

Comment: @Niladri i am using submit button to post the data what you are trying to say i am not getting actually, can you guide me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieve value from javascript function in codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136426/retrieve-value-from-javascript-function-in-codebehind)

Answer (score 0):

I think `return false` in end of JavaScript function (`GetSelectedRow`) causes this. `return false` prevents from `PostBack`. `PostBack` causes information to be send to the server and you can get `textbox.Text()` in code behind and use it. Delete `return false` from `GetSelectedRow` and check it again.